# how to create connection in oracle sql developer Version 18.1.0.095 in windows 7

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

i just install oracle sql developer to my pc windows 7 but when i tried to connecting its giving me **Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection** as per search in net manually i created folder C:\Oracle_Client\network\admin and there created tns.ora file but still i unable to connect my database anyone can help me how can i connect my db here is my tns.ora file

```
Flytech=
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Localhost)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = Flytech)
 )
)
```

Comment: Do you have a database on your windows box ?

Comment: yes i have database on my windows os

Comment: this err is basically sqldev can't connect to the network name in this case localhost:1521.  What is in your listener.ora?

Comment: Is it really "tns.ora" (as you put it, twice)? Because, it should be "tnsnames.ora". Just because you created a directory (the path you mentioned), Oracle won't know that it exists - try to create the TNS_ADMIN environment variable that points to that directory.

Comment: i already created tns_admin variable : C:\Oracle_Client\network\admin\tns.ora but still cant connect

Comment: as far as my knowledge if we created tns.ora then listener.ora not required is it?

Comment: After change name as tnsnames.ora connection has establish but asking me password so where should i put password in.ora file?

Comment: @atul password goes in the connection properties in sqldeveloper, not in any text file on your machine

Comment: listener.ora defines what ip|hostname and ports the DB Listener is listening on. that is what you then use in SQLDEV to connect. So yes there's a listener.ora somewhere or you need to setup one up.

Comment: @KrisRice : ok i tried to setup listener.ora file also but before that can you tell me how can i set password?

Comment: Let's backup.. How did you install the DB ?

Comment: normally download package from oracle side and run sqldeveloper

Comment: I believe there is a misunderstanding here, @Atul. SQL Developer is a GUI tool that allows you to connect to any Oracle databases. But in order to connect to an Oracle database you have to already have one. From your comment above it's not clear whether you just downloaded and installed SQL Developer or whether you also downloaded and installed an Oracle Database. Can you please clarify on the latter. Do you have an Oracle Database up and running? Did you go through a successful installation and created a database called `Flytech` as your tnsnames.ora hints above?

Comment: Sqldev does not include a database. You need to do that separate

Comment: So I Installed SQL Developer - Now What? https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303 - I wrote this for you @Atul :)